# Using gitattributes to replace repository line endings

Tags: git

I've attempted to normalize the line endings in a shared repository, which contains windows and unix specific files, but I am unable to get it acting how I expect it to work.

We all develop on Windows boxes, but require the line endings (depending on file type) to be LF or CRLF. Developers have been advised to keep autocrlf set to false so that some files which require CRLF to be present aren't changed inside the repository (there is a mixture of windows and unix file formats), and change the line endings manually if necessary.

Someone has advised that using gitattributes would go some way to alleviating the need to police which file endings should be used, but I have been unable to get this working.

These are my user git settings:

```
[core]
    eol = native
    bare = false
    filemode = false
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
    ignorecase = true
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    symlinks = false
    autocrlf = true
    editor = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -nosession -noPlugin
```

programdata git settings:

```
[core]
    fscache = true
```

repository git settings:

```
[core]
    logallrefupdates = true
```

.gitattributes file:

```
# convert all to lf
* text eol=lf

# convert these to windows line endings
*.sbm   text eol=crlf
*.sbp   text eol=crlf
*.sin   text eol=crlf
*.bat   text eol=crlf
*.cmd   text eol=crlf
*.ini   text eol=crlf
*.inf   text eol=crlf
/strataclient/BubbleHelp/* text eol=crlf

# don't touch binary files
*.dot   binary
*.dll   binary
*.exe   binary
*.ocx   binary
*.lic   binary
*.cfn   binary
```

To test it, I have created a small commit which contains the .gitattributes file (which I've been amending to test different combinations), and then run the following commands:

```
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
```

It seems to change some line endings, but not in the way I've been expecting.

I've attempted to follow various guides, but none seems to make the far reaching changes expected. I am expecting all text files to be changed to LF (e.g. java, properties, txt) unless it's one of the types listed to CRLF (e.g. cmd, bat).

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question by accident and I'm curious if this is still a problem after 2+ years?

Anyhoo! In recent Git versions you can just do a `git add --renormalize` after you have committed your *.gitattributes* file, as described here: [Configuring Git to handle line endings](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings)